# Is there a way to "feature flag" python dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, python-poetry, anaconda3

In Rust, you can use [features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) to gate entire sections of your application behind flags you set at build/dependency install time.

This allows you to, for example, enable "all" features, which is great for developers, or enable just "client" features, for released software (that may not need all the extra packages you use when debugging, like `deepdiff`).

Is there a way to do this in any of the major Python package managers (pip, poetry, anaconda)?

Comment: Packages can have optional dependencies specified as extras when using `pip install`; for example, `pip install requests` vs `pip install requests[socks]` [1](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/setup.py#L123). Does that help?

Comment: Note that rust needs features because it only _compiles_ the code, it doesn't run your program (it creates the binary, and then the OS your targeted for compilation runs that). Python, on the other hand, _runs_ the code you give it, so you have a million different ways (well okay, not quite a million) in which you can control whether something runs during any given invocation: you can look environment variables, you can create config files with fallback defaults, plain conditional logic based on what time of day it is, pretty much anything goes.

Comment: (and of course you can create separate `requirements.txt` files for devs vs. "end users" so that when someone runs `python -m pip install` in their local virtual environment, they only install what you think they need based on the kind of user you think they are)

Comment: Separate requirements.txt seems like the way to handle this, though that's sadly not a supported use case in any IDEs. If you want to write an answer about the requests[sock] possibility, I'm intrigued!